# How do I find the value divisible by 4 AND 5?

Tags: javascript

I need to print "foo bar" if the value of a number between 1 and 100 is divisible by 4 and 5.
**edit**: both 4 and 5

Here is what I have so far:

```
for(i = 1; i < 100; i++){
   if(i % 4 === 0){
      console.log("foo");
   } 
   else if(i % 5 === 0){
     console.log("bar");
   }
}
```

Comment: So it means the number should be divisible by 20.

Comment: for(i=20;i<=100;i+=20)

Comment: Do you mean that each number has to be dividable with both 4 and 5, or either 4 or 5?

Comment: aren't there correct answer? accept it if there is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(i=1; i<100; i++){
    if(i % 4 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("foobar");
    } 
    else if(i % 4 === 0) {
        console.log("foo");
    }
    else if(i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("bar");
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will also be true for "4 or 5" and OP asked for "4 and 5"

Comment: No, it uses the and operand. 4 or 5 would be ||

Comment: @LGSon this is a typical beginner question which is a reworded fizzbuzz program. The code I posted is definitely what OP is looking for.

Comment: @LGSon I do not understand the problem. The code I posted is added onto his original code, I think he can figure out which statement prints foobar, right? To me it seemed like he wanted to add the ability to print "foobar" as well as "foo" and "bar". Like I said, it's a beginner question we've all seen many times before.

Comment: Thank you. I couldnt find this anywhere, which was crazy. 
I am a beginner, I  had it like this first:  

`if(i % 4 && 5 === 0) {
        console.log("foobar");
    }`

Comment: @NathanAlexander No problem.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple maths, you can try to check it like this:

```
for(i=1; i<100; i++){
 if(i % 20 === 0){
   console.log("foo");
 } 
}
```

Comment: Note, that this only works because 4 and 5 are co-prime. The general formula for the divisor you have to look for is `x * y / gcd(x,y)`.

Comment: @filmor it's `lcm(x, y)`

Comment: True, that is equivalent, I just wanted to emphasise the fact that this is `x * y` if `gcd(x, y) = 1` (i.e. `x` and `y` are co-prime).

Answer (score 2):

You can combine these statements into one if:

```
if(i % 4 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)
{
    console.log("This number is both divisible by 4 and 5");
}
```

You can learn more about if and comparison operands [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp).

Answer (score 1):

What you have is printing *foo* for all numbers divisible by 4 and *bar* for all numbers divisible by 5. Then, your code excludes 100 from the values.
The right solution to your problem is:

```
for(i=1; i<=100; i++){
 if(i % 4 === 0 && i % 5 === 0){
   console.log("foo bar");
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually correct. If you want to know that value is divisble by 4 and 5 you need make modulo condition on both and check whether modulo is equal to 0

so proper condition is

```
for ( i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
     if (i % 4 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
       console.log("number is divisble by 4 and 5");
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
   var result;
   if(i % 4 === 0){
      result = "foo";
   } 
   //... perhaps, there are any conditions
   if(i % 5 === 0 && result){
     result += "bar";
     console.log(result);
   }
}
```

Second way:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
   var result;
   if(i % 4 === 0){
      result = "foo";
   } 
   //... perhaps, there are any conditions
   if(i % 5 === 0 && result){
     result += "bar";
   } else result = "";//or undefined

   if(result) console.log(result);
}
```